# matrix losing class attribute in R

Tags: oop, r, r-s3

Consider the following code:

```r
A <- matrix(1:12, ncol=4)
colnames(A) <- letters[1:4]
class(A) <- c("foo", "matrix")
```

when A is subset, it loses the "foo" class label:

```r
class(A[1:2,])
# [1] "matrix"
```

The same happens with vectors. Yet, the same doesn't happen with data.frames:

```r
B <- as.data.frame(A)
class(B) <- c("foo", "data.frame")
class(B[1:2,])
# [1] "foo"        "data.frame"
```

And usually, applying generic functions to objects preserves the class attribute. Not for matrix/numeric/integer objects. Why? And can this behavior be avoided?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

data.frames have their own subset method `[.data.frame`, which takes care of the class for you.  I'm not sure why the Primitive doesn't preserve the class, but it's pretty straight-forward to create your own subset method.

```
`[.foo` <- function(x, i, j, ...) {
  y <- unclass(x)[i,j,...]
  class(y) <- c("foo",class(y))
  y
}
class(A[1:2,])
# [1] "foo"    "matrix"
```

EDIT:
As others have mentioned, `NextMethod` should be used here.

```
`[.foo` <- `[.bar` <- function(x, i, j, ...) {
  y <- NextMethod(.Generic)
  class(y) <- .Class
  y
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought that adding a method for '[<-' would be an option. I would use the following: `'[.foo' <- function(x, i, j, ...) {y <- unclass(x);[i,j,...]; class(y) <- class(x) y}` because it works also if class(A) is c("boo","bar", "matrix").

Comment: Better to use NextMethod than unclasssing, which makes a copy